# The question you're *editing* appears subjective and is likely to be closed

Tags: bug, questions, edits

As I was editing [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25096312/3622940), it yells at me:

[image: img]

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

But I'm not asking the question, instead editing it - Should it not be "The question you're **editing** appears subjective and is likely to be closed." instead?

Comment: Just fix the title *"How to store input..."*

Comment: @brasofilo: this is not about how to quell the error message.

Comment: Meh. Why complicate the system.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I didn't post an answer, just a sideline comment ;)

Comment: This is very minor (and unlikely to become a priority), however, technically you are correct. I believe nobody should be downvoted to report an actual issue (as minor as it is).

Comment: I would actually be nice to read something telling you to perhaps address the subjective nature of the question, if you're editing it anyway.

Comment: It needed editing, it's on-hold now...

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I realized it was subjective and wanted to improve it at first, but then I noticed the mis-preposition in the message and made a Meta post. No good now...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The extra logic for checking whether you're answering or editing could be avoided by simplifying the message to

> This question appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

The fact that you're *asking* the question seems redundant anyhow, especially since the tooltip also has a little arrow pointing to it.

Comment: I like this proposal, it is feasible as well.